# Removing CSS On Webpage from Masterpage

Tags: css, master-pages

I have multiple webpages that work together. Most of them have the same css from a master file. The issue I am having is that one page needs the css to be a little different. Here is what I mean:

**Master's CSS**

```
  .Close
  {
      position: relative;
      top: 0px; /* Different */
      display: block; /* Different */
      margin: auto; /* Different */
  }

.ArrowLeft
{
    background-image: url(arrow_left.png);
    border: 0 none transparent;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    height: 37px;
    width: 47px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: left; /* Different */
}

.ArrowRight
{
    background-image: url(arrow_right.png);
    border: 0 none transparent;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    height: 37px;
    width: 47px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: right; /* Different */
}
```

**Page's CSS**

```
.ArrowLeft
{
    background-image: url(arrow_left.png);
    border: 0 none transparent;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 24px;
    width: 25px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
}

.ArrowRight
{
    background-image: url(arrow_right.png);
    border: 0 none transparent;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 258px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 25px;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
}

  .Close
  {
      position: relative;
      top: -1px;
      left: 105px;
  }
```

Notice the small differences (`margin: auto`, `float: left` .. ect) I want to have these differences not happen in my page's css. I know that `float: none` will remove the `floats` but how can i remove the `display`, `top`, and `margin` properties that are different? I would just change the class name but all the pages use the same .js file so renaming them would be very long/unwanted.

Suggestions?

Is there a way to just turn off the master css or disable it for these classes?

**Edit** Here is what I am talking about (The arrow):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it like this:

Master head section:

```
<head>
    <!-- other head stuff -->

    <link href="css/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="CPH_Css" runat="server" />
</head>
```

ContentPage:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPH_Css" runat="server">
    <link href="css/content.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
```

That way you can override the master.css with whatever specifics you want in the content page.

Comment: That is how I do it to. I have the master over-ridden by the other css where i can, but the `display` `top` and `float` are not in the page's css, so there is no values to override them

Comment: So why not put them into the page's css and override them with the value that you want in the page?

Comment: That's what I am doing. The problem is I don't know how to overwrite `margin`. Ill show it in an image from firebug in an edit. I think that I am not explaining my question right

Comment: Your `top` value is getting overridden.  As you said, `float: none`, will get rid of the floats.  For margin you could always do `margin: auto;` in your page to override that.  And for display, it's up to you, block or inline or whatever else you want for that page.

Comment: I just changed `margin: auto` to `margin: 0`. That worked well enough. The rest of your suggestions fixed everything else